# MySQL bulk permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions, bulk

Is there any way to grant bulk permissions in MySQL to several users (on the same database) whose username is equal to all of them but not their hostname/IP?

I mean users like these:

user@192.168.0.1,user@192.168.0.2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your users already exist, you can use the following syntax:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON testDatabase.*
TO 'user', 'admin', 'root', 'john'
```

You can not specify the `@` tag for this particular operation. The users must be defined before running the `GRANT`

Comment: I cannot vote your comment, 'cause I low on reputation. Thx.